# What time unit is used in the Visual Studio 2010 instrumentation profiler?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, profiling

The profiler in Visual Studio 2010 is great and all, but I can't see what unit the time results in the instrumentation profiler is reported in. The results table is just numbers and I can't find anywhere in the UI where I can set the unit (as [there is in e.g. AQTime](http://smartbear.com/support/viewarticle/17717/)).

[image]

I've read through the "[Understanding Instrumentation Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182369.aspx)" section on MSDN but it just uses *time* to explain the numbers. (*"The total time that was spent executing..."*)

Does anyone know what unit (milliseconds, microseconds, ticks, etc.) that is used? I'm guessing milliseconds but I'm not 100% sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time is in milliseconds (msec) or processor cycles (ticks).

According to [the MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255356%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) (It refers to vs2008 but it's still the same):

> The time in milliseconds **(msec)** or processor cycles **(ticks)** that was
>   spent in the direct execution of this function, excluding time spent
>   in child functions called by this function.

Comment: *"or"*? Which one is it? Also, do you have any sources?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255356%28v=vs.90%29.aspx
It refers to vs2008 but it's still the same

Answer (score 6):

I found there's a tooltip on the column headers on the result table which states *"The time spent in this function (msec)"* which confirms that it is indeed milliseconds.

[image: Tooltip has the answer]